# How to record FM radio

Tags: fm-radio, huawei-u8150, audio-recording

Is there an app which can record
audio (to mp3) from the FM radio (**NOT** internet-radio).

I want to record some shows while listening to the radio and store them in my SD memory card but I can't seem to find any suitable application.

My phone is a Huawei U8150 and I'm using Android 2.1.

Comment: Why not play the radio over the speaker (with headset acting as antenna) and record it with another device such as microphone... really in short, the FM radio facility is not de-facto standard and will vary upon the manufacturer's chipset integrated into handset. What's wrong with using TuneIn (Internet radio)?

Comment: Weird. Far as I remember my S3 Mini was able to record FM Radio with Stock radio app.

Answer (score 2):

Android's doesn't have an integrated FM radio functionality (API), if a device features FM support, it was added by the manufacturer.

Because of that there's no standard way to access it via 3rd party apps. You can try this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tarsys.fmradiorecordertest) but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

The [Spirit FM Radio Unlocked](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mikersmicros.fm_unlock) has slight support for recording. Most of it is experimental however.

There are no other tuned FM radio apps on the market, that run on all devices.

The only way to get full FM recording facilities, is if your OEM puts this feature into the stock FM radio app.